# If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then must $m^2 - p^k = s^2 - t^2$ hold for some $s$ and $t$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

My present question is as is in the title:

> If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then must $m^2 - p^k = s^2 - t^2$ hold for some $s$ and $t$?

It is known that $m^2 - p^k$ is not a square.

I note the following:

---

For an *even* perfect number $2^{q-1}(2^q - 1)$ with Mersenne prime $2^q - 1$, then we have
$$2^{q-1} - (2^q - 1) = 1 - 2^{q - 1}$$
which is a difference of two squares.

Notice that
$$2^{(q-1)/2} < 2^q - 1$$
holds unconditionally.

---

If indeed, $m^2 - p^k$ can be written in the form $m^2 - p^k = s^2 - t^2$, and in addition, $1 \leq t \leq 2$, then we have
$$(m+s)(m-s) = m^2 - s^2 = p^k - t^2 > 0.$$
This will imply that
$$(m+s) \mid p^k - t^2$$
from which it would follow that
$$m < m+s \leq p^k - t^2 < p^k.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Since $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, and $m$ is odd, we have $m^2-p^k\equiv 0\pmod{4}$.  The only integers that are not differences of squares are exactly those that are $2\pmod{4}$.

Comment: My profuse thanks to you for your response, @PaceNielsen! (This means too much to me. Muchos gracias!)